# How do I connect to Informix with .NET?

Tags: .net, database, odbc, oledb, informix

Background Information:

- Visual Studio 2010 (.NET Framework 4.0)
- Informix Server 7.31
- Informix ClientSDK 3.50 TC7 (Windows 32-bit) was installed as well.

I have tried multiple ways suggested online to connect to the Informix server, but all of them  do not work for me for whatever reason. I have looked at articles such as [Connect Informix with ADO.Net](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/) and I have used [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix) to generate a connection string.

When I go to Visual Studio I do the following:

1. Server Explorer
2. Right-click on Data Connections > Add Connection...
3. Microsoft ODBC Data Source | .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC
4. Use connection string (copied/pasted using the [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix) website).
5. Test Connection

RESULT: ERROR [IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

1. Server Explorer
2. Right-click on Data Connections > Add Connection...
3. Other | .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC
4. Use connection string (copied/pasted using the [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix) website).
5. Test Connection

RESULT: ERROR [IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

1. Server Explorer
2. Right-click on Data Connections > Add Connection...
3. Other | .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB
4. OLE DB Provider: IBM Informix OLE DB Provider
5. Data Links...

RESULT: The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Beyond that I wasn't sure what to really fill in there...

Oh, and I even tried to use the [sample code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=95047&filename=IfxAdo.zip&method=http&locale=worldwide) provided in the [first article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/), substituting in my connection information:

- HOST: The IP of the server
- SERVICENUM: The Port Number
- SERVER: The servers name
- DATABASE: The database I'm working on
- USER: user id
- PASS: password

Sample code I downloaded/altered:

```
using System;
using IBM.Data.Informix;

namespace IfxAdoPres.Basics {
    public class BasicConnection {
        const string HOST = "192.168.OBFUSCATED";
        const string SERVICENUM = "5000";
        const string SERVER = "myServer";
        const string DATABASE = "myDatabase";
        const string USER = "myUserID";
        const string PASSWORD = "myPassword";

        public IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection();
        public BasicConnection() {}

        public void MakeConnection() {
            string ConnectionString = "Host = " + HOST + "; " +
                "Service=" + SERVICENUM + "; " +
                "Server=" + SERVER + "; " +
                "Database=" + DATABASE + "; " +
                "User Id=" + USER + "; " +
                "Password=" + PASSWORD + "; ";

            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        }

        public void CloseConnection() {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString; The exception states "Invalid argument" with no InnerException (basically very unhelpful). The callstack is:

- Basics.exe!IfxAdoPres.Basics.BasicConnection.MakeConnection()
- Basics.exe!IfxAdoPres.Basics.Test.Main(string[] args = {string[0]})
- [External Code]

I am stuck and have no idea what to do... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I went back to the article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/

After uninstalling everything and starting out fresh, the demo code seemed to work after installing the IBM Informix Client SDK 3.5 and using Setnet32 to configure my settings.

I must've had something corrupt since I had a couple of different of versions of the Informix Driver installed initially.

Comment: I know this is a super old post and you might not remember but I am having the same problems. Do you happen to remember if you had to add the IBM.DATA.Informix in your project references? There isn't a lot of information out in the wild... I installed the latest client sdk and trying to setup a mock connection just to hit the try catch which should hit the catch but it throws the same error you had which is invalid argument doesn't make any sense to me.